# How to use "date" and "number" type TextBox in ASP.NET 2.0 and allow server side for them

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I am working in ASP.NET framework 2.0 and i want to use the `Date`, `Time` and `Number` text box fields as below,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text_number" TextMode="Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="text_date" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="text_time" TextMode="Time" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

But i know we cannot use like this since framework 2.0 does not support `Date`, `Time` and `Number` types for `<asp:TextBox>`. I used the following,

```
<input id="date_value" type="date" runat="server" />
<input id="time_value" type="time" runat="server" />
<input id="number_value" type="number" runat="server" />
```

Here it works but here i am not able to access the fields in server side and i get error in server side as below,

```
'date' is not a valid type for an input tag.
'time' is not a valid type for an input tag.
'number' is not a valid type for an input tag.
```

Is there any way i can use `Date`, `Time` and `Number` and also can access them in server side using `C#` in `ASP.NET 2.0` framework? (Only want to use framework 2.0 and not higher framework)

**EDIT**

I have tried like this but still not working

```
<asp:TextBox ID="mydate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="anotherdate" type="date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mydate.Attributes.Add("type", "date");
}
```

But this is what i get, normal textbox

[image]

**FULL CODE**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="BCPDetails.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="mydate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="anotherdate" type="date" runat="server" </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The text type of a textbox control is only ever going to be single or multiple line and you need to use the type attribute as if it were standard html control

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this, asp will render the type attribute as is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text_number" type="number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="text_date" type="date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="text_time" type="time" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**you could also try the following**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text_number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="text_date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="text_time" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

and in the **code behind**

```
text_number.Attributes.Add("type", "number");
text_date.Attributes.Add("type", "date");
text_time.Attributes.Add("type", "time");
```

the code behind solution is sure to work

Comment: I tried but it wont do that..it only shows normal text box

Comment: @ManoUncharted - I have updated my answer with another solution to set the attribute in code behind, please try it. I am sure it will work for you

Comment: @ManoUncharted can you share the rendered html for me.

Comment: I have added them in my question EDIT please check

Comment: i have edited the question..added the full page code

Comment: Sorry, I meant can you inspect the text boxes that are rendered and let tell me what u see?

Comment: @ManoUncharted Right-click on the browser window, choose "view source" and look for the html that is generated for your textboxes.